# APE (Ajax Push Engine) Tutorial

Tags: ajax, push, ape

I've been having problems trying to setup APE on the server side... are there any video tutorials or any tutorials which are more detailed than the one provided on their site?

Answer (score 6):

Even though this is an old question, I'm in the process of installing APE and I found this which seems useful: http://www.ifc0nfig.com/ape-an-introduction/

Answer (score 3):

From their homepage: http://www.ape-project.org/wiki/index.php/Setup

From their google groups: http://groups.google.com/group/ape-project/web/installing-ape-on-ubuntu-9-04

Comment: @timmy was this not helpful ?

Answer (score 1):

Strange to post my own link, I know, but I wrote a small guide as well:

http://www.xosofox.de/2010/03/playing-with-my-new-pet-ape/

http://www.xosofox.de/2010/11/get-your-ape-up-to-date/